# An adjective for the time that is excited by Christmas?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

The time leading to Christmas festival is kind of exciting, cheerful, active, etc.

Is "Christmas-excited time" a correct phrase when we mean to say the above point?

Example:

> During this **Christmas-excited time**, I like to be alone.

Or other suggestion?

Comment: I think you mean "excited" rather than "exited". There are the terms "Christmas season" and "holiday season", but they don't directly imply excitement. However, if you were to say "During the holiday season, I like to be alone" I think people would make the association.

Comment: In BrE it is called the 'festive season' - not sure if that is colloquial in AmE.

Comment: Holiday season over here, although festive season was my immediate impression.

Comment: "Advent" (as either a noun or adjective) is pretty good if you don't mind ending on Christmas, and don't mind the Christian connotation.  Otherwise, "holidays" or "holiday season" (which generally is considered to continue past Jan 1, perhaps out to Epiphany on Jan 6).

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=festive+season%2Cchristmas&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfestive%20season%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchristmas%3B%2Cc0) the '**festive season**' is apparently as common a way to describe Christmas as is 'Christmas' itself.

BrE uses it more often than 'Christmas', AmE less so.

> People sometimes refer to the Christmas period as **the festive season.**
>
> "For many of us, the festive season can be one of the most stressful times of the year."

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/festive-season)

Answer (score 3):

Per [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/holiday_season):

> **holiday season**
>
> NOUN
>
> (in the US) the period of time from Thanksgiving until New Year, including such festivals as Christmas, Hanukkah, and Kwanzaa.

Or, also per [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/advent):

> **Advent**
>
> NOUN
>
> 2. The first season of the Church year, leading up to Christmas and including the four preceding Sundays.

Or, per [American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=yule):

> **Yule**
>
> n.
>
> Christmas or the Christmas season, especially as traditionally celebrated in Northern Europe and North America with customs stemming in part from pagan celebrations of the winter solstice.

And, further from [American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Yuletide):

> **Yuletide**
>
> n.
>
> The season of Yule.

Comment: Not me, and thanks for such a detailed explanation of the AmE term. Maybe some Anglophile would have liked a BrE version. In England we do not celebrate thanksgiving, so the only term for that period is Advent. Apart from Christian religious observance, and gross commercial promotion, the only significant activity surrounds advent calendars, in which day by day, a new window is opened yielding something interesting or pleasing.

Comment: Interesting. I've no context for Advent, myself. I thought it to be a Catholic ritual (and England to be primarily Protestant).

Comment: I was brought up in the (protestant) Church of England, and not in the high Anglo-Catholic version either. Nevertheless Advent was a season well known in my church. Besides which, people sell Advent calendars!

Comment: @jtheletter - Advent is definitely a "thing" with Lutherans in the US.

Comment: I found "Advent" in my NOAD and on their website, so I've added it above. Thanks very much for the tip. Good to know. Cheers.

Comment: Tangentially, consider "Holiday Spirit"

Comment: @HotLicks: and the Lutherans have all the good Advent hymns.